# Same LUN trough FC and iSCI to different hosts

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, iscsi

On my small vMware lab I'm presenting the same LUN to both ESXi hosts, one from FC and another from iSCSI. iSCSI finds the devices but doesn't mount the datastore. As I can see disks have different identifiers.

Thank you

Comment: What's the name of your SAN? Model?

Comment: It's not a Branded SAN, it's CentOS 7 running SCST but the iSCSI module fails to start so I installed and configured targetcli.